# Register user by using ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I'm newbie to jQuery mobile 1.4.3 and javascript, I'm trying to register a new user sending an AJAX Post call to the a web service and I'm lost...

The user registration has to send the following JSON to the web service:

> {
>
> "userName": "sample string 1",
>
> "email": "sample string 2",
>
> "password": "sample string 3",
>
> "confirmPassword": "sample string 4",
>
> "name": "sample string 5",
>
> "deviceId": "sample string 6"
>
> }

The web service url: http://company.ac-web-systems.eu/api/account/register

My AJAX code:

```
    var formData = {
    "userName": "user1",
        "email": "email@mail.com",
        "password": "123456",
        "confirmPassword": "123456",
        "name": "name1",
        "deviceId": "12121212121212"
};


// process the form
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://compay.ac-web-systems.eu/api/account/register', 
    data: formData, // our data object
    dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
    encode: true
})
// using the done promise callback
.done(function (data) {

    // log data to the console so we can see
    console.log(data);


    // here we will handle errors and validation messages
});
```

I'm pretty sure the dataForm data structure or the way the data is assembled isn't correct.

I also need some advice if this is the correct way to connect to a web service or is there another better and faster option for jQuery mobile?

Really need a help here.

Thanks in Advance.

**UPDATE**

I can't seem to reach the service here is the real url: http://yolp.ac-web-systems.eu/api/account/register

Comment: can you reach your web service url? I cant...

Comment: Are you using CORS? If not try using jsonp instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain for more details

Comment: updated with the real web service url

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
encode: true
```

Your data object is already a json object.

Answer (score 0):

On: http://jsfiddle.net/2a3tH/1/

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

This will probably help you:
["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: I'm using google POSTMAN to test the api call and still no success